# Format cell color based on value in another sheet and cell

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with two sheets. I would like to format the cell background color in the first column of sheet 1 based on the values in the second column of sheet 2.

For example, if the value of of sheet2, row 6, column 2 is say, 4, then I would like the background color of sheet 1, row 4, column 1 to be green. If none of the values in sheet 2, column 2 reference a particlar row in sheet 1, I'd like to leave it set to no color. There's no prohibition against the same value appearing multiple times in the second column of sheet 2. Bonus kudos if you can tell me how to unset the color if the last value in sheet 2 pointing to a row in sheet 1 is removed.

I'm sure that for the Excel wizards out there this could be trivial, but I rarely have occasion to use excel and certainly don't have time to become a black belt in it. Can anyone offer me advice, pointers, or a quick formula to do this? If this is going to take some complex VB code to implement, it isn't worth it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a place to get answers, or is it a place to debate semantics? I don't see why applying formulas in Excel isn't a form of programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I did it in Excel 2003 using conditional formatting.

To apply conditional formatting to `Sheet1` using values from `Sheet2`, you need to mirror the values into `Sheet1`.

### Creating a mirror of Sheet2, column B in Sheet 1

1. Go to `Sheet1`.
2. Insert a new column by right-clicking column A's header and selecting "Insert".
3. Enter the following formula into A1:

   `=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!B1),"",Sheet2!B1)`
4. Copy `A1` by right-clicking it and selecting "`Copy`".
5. Paste the formula into column `A` by right-clicking its header and selecting "`Paste`".

`Sheet1`, column `A` should now exactly mirror the values in `Sheet2`, column `B`.

(Note: if you don't like it in column `A`, it works just as well to have it in column `Z` or anywhere else.)

### Applying the conditional formatting

1. Stay on `Sheet1`.
2. Select column `B` by left-clicking its header.
3. Select the menu item `Format > Conditional Formatting...`
4. Change `Condition 1` to "`Formula is`" and enter this formula:

   `=MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0)`
5. Click the `Format...` button and select a green background.

You should now see the green background applied to the matching cells in `Sheet1`.

### Hiding the mirror column

1. Stay on `Sheet1`.
2. Right-click the header on column `A` and select "`Hide`".

This should automatically update `Sheet1` whenever anything in `Sheet2` is changed.

Comment: +1, this is it, except it doesn't quite work how I wanted it to, I think it assumes column B's values are row numbers. I need B to be green if its value appears in any cell in A. So this change works for me: =MATCH(B1,$A:$A,0).  Make this change in solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this with ***named ranges*** so you don't have to copy the cells from Sheet1 to Sheet2:

1. Define a named range, say `Sheet1Vals` for the column that has the values on which you want to base your condition. You can define a new named range by  using the `Insert\Name\Define...` menu item. Type in your name, then use the cell browser in the `Refers to` box to select the cells you want in the range. If the range will change over time (add or remove rows) you can use this formula instead of selecting the cells explicitly:

   `=OFFSET('SheetName'!$COL$ROW,0,0,COUNTA('SheetName'!$COL:$COL))`.

   Add a `-1` before the last `)` if the column has a header row.
2. Define a named range, say `Sheet2Vals` for the column that has the values you want to conditionally format.
3. Use the Conditional Formatting dialog to create your conditions. Specify `Formula Is` in the dropdown, then put this for the formula:

   `=INDEX(Sheet1Vals, MATCH([FirstCellInRange],Sheet2Vals))=[Condition]`

   where `[FirstCellInRange]` is the address of the cell you want to format and `[Condition]` is the value your checking.

For example, if my conditions in Sheet1 have the values of `1`, `2` and `3` and the column I'm formatting is column `B` in Sheet2 then my conditional formats would be something like:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1Vals, MATCH(B1,Sheet2Vals))=1
=INDEX(Sheet1Vals, MATCH(B1,Sheet2Vals))=2
=INDEX(Sheet1Vals, MATCH(B1,Sheet2Vals))=3
```

You can then use the format painter to copy these formats to the rest of the cells.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In Google Sheets you can reference with `=indirect("NamedRange")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Excel 2003 -

The problem with using conditional formatting here is that you can't reference another worksheet or workbook in your conditions.  What you can to do is set some column on sheet 1 equal to the appropriate column on sheet 2 (in your example =Sheet2!B6).  I used Column F in my example below. Then you can use conditional formatting.  Select the cell at Sheet 1, row , column 1 and then go to the conditional formatting menu. Choose "Formula Is" from the drop down and set the condition to "=$F$6=4".  Click on the format button and then choose the Patterns tab.  Choose the color you want and you're done.

You can use the format painter tool to apply conditional formatting to other cells, but be aware that by default Excel uses absolute references in the conditions. If you want them to be relative you'll need to remove the dollar signs from the condition.

You can have up to 3 conditions applied to a cell (use the add >> button at the bottom of the Conditional formatting dialog) so if the last row is fixed (for example, you know that it will always be row 10)  you can use it as a condition to set the background color to none.  Assuming that the last value you care about is in row 10 then (still assuming that you've set column F on sheet1 to the corresponding cells on sheet 2) then set the 1st condition to Formula Is   =$F$10="" and the pattern to None.  Make it the first condition and it will override any following conflicting statements.

Comment: You can reference another worksheet if you use a named range in your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution for restoring the original colors when copying certain highly formatted sheets or templates to a new spreadsheet.. it copies all data directly, so it only works if you need to copy a sheet, not only apply colors to a different sheet with different data:

copy the original format workbook by ctrl + g and selecting the appropriate range

paste it into the new work sheet, colors will be all changed

with the destination still highlighted, right click and go to "Paste special" and select "All using source theme", then repeat the paste special, only with "Values" this time, and it should be identical to the original sheet you copied

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before with [conditional formatting](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel). It's a great way to visually inspect the cells in a workbook and spot the outliers in your data.

Comment: +1 For a great link, although it doesn't address my need to reference a second sheet.