# Highlight differences between two sheets in Excel 2007 or 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

A question like this has been asked before but I couldn't seem to find the answer I wanted.

The problem is that conditional formatting rules can't normally refer to cells in another sheet. However answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451297/format-cell-color-based-on-value-in-another-sheet-and-cell) show how you can get round it so I'm proposing to answer my own question although any input would be appreciated of course.

So I've got an original sheet that looks like this

[image]

and a working version that looks initially like this

[image]

and want to highlight any differences between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer as suggested in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451297/format-cell-color-based-on-value-in-another-sheet-and-cell) is to use a named range to refer to the original sheet from within the working sheet.

So all you need to do is:-

Set up a named range say OriginalTopLeft equal to

```
OriginalVersion!a1
```

In conditional formatting, enter the formula

```
=A1<>OriginalTopLeft
```

and choose the formatting you want to apply and the range you want to apply it to. Relative addressing handles the rest.

[image]

Comment: It's a different question, I think all I've done is borrow my approach from one of the answers. My issue is, that if I search for something like "highlight difference between two excel sheets" I can't find much of an answer except "Use Excel 2013" or "Copy into the other sheet" or "Use this macro that I've written".