# VBA copy sheet from one workbook to another (values and format only)

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have the following code to copy and paste one sheet from one wb to another:

```
 wb1.Worksheets("ws").Copy After:=wb2.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
```

I'm trying to only paste values and formatting, how would I go about doing this?

Also the process is taking a longer that expected time, possibly because the sheet I'm copying from contains a pivot table with a large amount of data. Is there anyway I can speed it up?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency. Copy & Pasting is slower than setting Rng2.Value to being Rng1.Value and then using .NumberFormat etc to make Rng2 like Rng1. You'd have to do `Worksheets.Add` first.

```
Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value
Rng2.NumberFormat = Rng1.NumberFormat
```

Do you want fonts etc as well?

If you want to do Copy & Paste then you could do paste-special values and then paste-special formats but that'll be slower.

Comment: The only thing is that it is copy from a filtered pivot table, if I iterate through each cell and paste, then it'll just paste everything from the table, filtered or not right?

Comment: You could use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to only use the visible cells if you're filtering the rest. This should be OK as a range.

Comment: Ok great thanks, seems to work! But yes I would like to get Fonts/ColorFills formatting as well, how would I go about do that?

Comment: You could try and use the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947950/). I tried it but it didn't work if you had more than one colour very well e.g. `Range("D1:E2").Interior.Color = Range("A1:B2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` turned out all black because I set the 4 cells to have different colours.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally just want the values, you can skip copy/paste (and thus using the clipboard) altogether by setting two ranges equal to eachother:

`=Range([copy TO range]).Value = Range([copy FROM range]).Value`.

But you are adding the worksheet at the same time, so add a line that creates the blank worksheet, then do

`wb2.sheets([worksheet name]).Value = wb1.worksheets("ws").value`

Comment: Will this work for a filtered table? I'm trying to grab only a select amount of data from the sheet (filtered out already) and I think if I just iterate through ranges it'll copy everything right?

Comment: @ViggieSmalls - Hm, I'm not sure, but it should. As long as you can accurately set the ranges, this method works.  Meaning, don't use `Sheets.Value = Sheets.Value`, you want to adjust the ranges to (for example), `worksheet2.Range("Z1:Z100").Value ` Worksheet1.Range("A1:A100").Value`.